# Clear Bootstrap 5 client-side validation on focus with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make use of Bootstrap 5's client-side validation. However, I don't find these as good a user experience as I would like - after clicking the submit button, the `is-invalid` class remains until the correct input is typed. I want it so that the `is-invalid` class is also cleared as soon as the user focuses the input, but I can't seem to accomplish this - once the Submit button has been pressed, no amount of clearing the `is-invalid` class on a focus event with jQuery or vanilla JavaScript (which I would prefer) has any result.

I have the `novalidate` attribute set on my form as well as a `needs-validation` class, and the form  contains two divs with `invalid-tooltip` on them (instead of `invalid-feedback`).

```
<form class="my-0 container needs-validation" method="POST" action="" novalidate>
<div class="col-lg-12 row py-4 px-5 gx-5">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 px-2 position-relative">
        <label class="mb-3" for="code">1. Enter your code:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" id="code" aria-label="Enter your code" placeholder="1234" 
        required minlength="4">
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Enter a valid code.</div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 px-2 my-4 my-lg-0 align-self-lg-start">
        <label class="mb-3" for="email">2. Enter your email address:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" aria-label="Enter your email address" placeholder="myemailaddress@example.com" required>
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Enter a valid email.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
        <button class="btn btn-primary text-wrap mx-2" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript I'm currently using to handle the Submit, taken from the [Bootstrap 5 documentation on validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation):

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
        form.addEventListener(
            "submit",
            function (event) {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.stopPropagation();
                }

                form.classList.add("was-validated");
            },
            false
        );
    });
})();
```

What's the best way to go about doing what I want (preferably in pure JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I added the following jQuery solution that I came across directly after the one provided by the Bootstrap documentation. Unfortunately my JavaScript is too rusty to convert it to ES6 let alone integrate it with the Bootstrap JavaScript solution, so I'm reliant on someone else to come along and do that for me, but either way it works very well as a more modern, instant way to deliver client-side validation feedback.

I also modified it to make the feedback on input instead of focus, which feels more instant and therefore in line with what users except, but this can easily be reverted by changing the `input` event in the function back to `focus` or any other event.

```
$(function () {
    $(".needs-validation")
        .find("input,select,textarea")
        .on("input", function () {
            $(this)
                .removeClass("is-valid is-invalid")
                .addClass(this.checkValidity() ? "is-valid" : "is-invalid");
        });
});
```

Comment: Did you or can you post a JS Fiddle of this? I replicated it in my local environment, but I keep getting errors.